# create a cell for a java.lang.Object

Tags: java, apache-poi

Im trying to add data to a excel sheet with Apache POI but at compile time i dont know what  type the actual data objects are which im trying to add to the sheet.

Is there some nice way to just do someThing like

```
Object obj= someObject;
cell.setValue(obj);
```

without doing the boilerplate of if/else and instanceof calls to determine whether obj is boolean, date, string, or numeric.

If the object is neither of these types i would expect Obj.toString(); to end up in the cell.

Comment: Version of POI?  Version of Office you're targeting?

Comment: currently @version 3.6, though upgrading may be an option.

Comment: using both versions of excel (xsl/xlsx) so though the org.poi.ss interfaces would be best.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of boilerplate if/else, can't you just overload your method parameters so that you have one method call for each case.